# How can I change the keys on iOS soft keyboard keys in a Javascript/HTML5/Cordova app

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

Inside the Twitter iphone app the popup keyboard has been modified so there is a "#" button and an "@" button in the bottom corner, whilst "return" has been removed (and replaced by a separate "tweet" button above the keyboard).

[image: twitter keyboard on iphone]

I am building a cross-platform web app (the iphone app is made using Cordova) and would like to do a similar thing with custom keyboard buttons for punctuation characters our users will enter frequently.

Does anybody know how to do this from within Javascript/CSS/HTML5/Cordova ?